the browser blocks pop-ups when the page is closed (onbeforeunload event) I want to display a confirm window
the browser displays an error in the console: Blocked confirm("Close?") during beforeunload
my code:
JavaScript

    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        if (confirm('Вы действительно хотите закрыть эту вкладку?')) {
            window.location.href = 'https://www.example.com/';
        }
        return "Вы точно хотите уйти без сохранение?";

    }

What should I do to prevent the browser from blocking my code?

most browsers prevent this behavior to stop abuse (Eg: not allow code to prevent the user from closing the tab)
You should run e.preventDefualt() and return false... most browsers will automatically show a pop up asking for confirmation
